# How to update every nth row

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update every nth row, but I want each account to start at 1:
This is what I want:

```
RowID|account|code|date
1    |123456 |123 |07-26-2016
2    |123456 |123 |07-27-2016
3    |123456 |123 |07-28-2016
4    |123456 |123 |07-29-2016
1    |456789 |543 |07-28-2016
2    |456789 |543 |07-29-2016
3    |456789 |543 |07-30-2016
1    |987654 |721 |07-28-2016
2    |987654 |721 |07-29-2016
3    |987654 |721 |07-30-2016
```

This is what I get:

```
RowID|account|code|date
1    |123456 |123 |07-26-2016
2    |123456 |123 |07-27-2016
3    |123456 |123 |07-28-2016
4    |123456 |123 |07-29-2016
5    |456789 |543 |07-28-2016
6    |456789 |543 |07-29-2016
7    |456789 |543 |07-30-2016
8    |987654 |721 |07-28-2016
9    |987654 |721 |07-29-2016
10   |987654 |721 |07-30-2016
```

This is all I have so far

```
;WITH x AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY account ASC) AS RowID, *
FROM roomblock
    WHERE account IS NOT NULL)
SELECT *
    FROM x
        WHERE RowID % 2 = 0
```

I want to update every 2nd row of each account to change the code to something else

Comment: what is the expected result ? Edit your post and write it down. Also what is wrong with your current query ?

Comment: Just made a change, the table on the bottom is what I get, the table on top is what I want.

Comment: And where is your input  table ? how do you expect people to figure that out on their own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
;WITH x AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by account  ORDER BY date ASC) AS RowID, *
FROM roomblock
    WHERE account IS NOT NULL)
SELECT *
    FROM x
        WHERE RowID % 2 = 0
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!